# balances stuck in contract

Tags: solidity, remix, balances

I'm running a MLM binary tree project, and when users register, they have to pay a fee which will be divided into two things: 90% for contract balance and the rest is a reward for their root user. however, when I'm trying to withdraw the rewards, it just wont. balances got saved in contract and can't get them back to users. here's the code:

```
Contract binaryMLM {

     mapping(address => uint256) public balances;
     address[] private addresses;
     event Withdrawal(address indexed user, uint256 amount);


function Withdraw() public {
    require(block.timestamp >= lastWithdrawTime + 24 hours, "You can call this function only once every 24 hours");
    lastWithdrawTime = block.timestamp;
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
        address _address = addresses[i];
        if (balances[_address] > 0) {
            IERC20(address(this)).transfer(_address, balances[_address]);
            emit Withdrawal(_address, balances[_address]);
            totalRewardPayment += balances[_address];
            balances[_address] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is binaryMLM a ERC20 contract? and if the transaction executed successfully or it failed?

Comment: @AllenWong it interacts with a erc20 token using ierc20 instance and execution is succesful.

Comment: then you should do `IERC20(tokenAddress).transfer(_address, balances[_address]);` instead

Comment: This line is suspicious `IERC20(address(this)).transfer(_address, balances[_address])`. Why do you want to transfer balances from the contract to the users? Also, if the contract has too many users the function could lead to a denial of service.

Comment: What is the question you're trying to have answered? Feel free to reference this to edit your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing the rest of your code, but this is the issue as I interpret it:

What erc20 token are you using? You are doing `IERC20(address(this))`, meaning you're calling the `transfer` function on the binaryMLM contract *itself*. You need to put the address of the token you want to transfer, not the address of the contract that is doing the transfer (your `binaryMLM` contract). If the execution isn't reverting then I assume you have a fallback function in `binaryMLM`

Also a small feedback, I would avoid doing a for loop like that in the `withdraw` function. This is generally bad practice because once `addresses` reaches a certain size, it will become impossible to call the function due to the fact that it will take more gas than can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead.

Contract binaryMLM {
mapping(address => uint256) public balances;
address[] private addresses;
uint256 public lastWithdrawTime;
uint256 public totalRewardPayment;
event Withdrawal(address indexed user, uint256 amount);

```
 function Withdraw() public {
     require(block.timestamp >= lastWithdrawTime + 24 hours, "You can call this function only once every 24 hours");
     lastWithdrawTime = block.timestamp;
     for (uint256 i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
         address _address = addresses[i];
         if (balances[_address] > 0) {
             uint256 _amount = balances[_address];
             require(IERC20(address(this)).transfer(_address, _amount), "Transfer failed");
             emit Withdrawal(_address, _amount);
             totalRewardPayment += _amount;
             balances[_address] = 0;
         }
     }
 }
```

}